# OpenShot Video Editor blurs the video recorded by Simple Screen Recorder

Tags: sound, video, video-editor, openshot

I am working on YouTube videos. I recorded my screen using Simple screen Recorder. The quality of this recording was very good. I recorded sound on my mobile phone, as its mic is of good quality. I merged these two files using OpenShot Video Editor. But the resulting video is a little blurry.

Which output option in OpenShot should I use to get the same video quality produced by simple screen recorder file even after getting merged with the sound file?

Answer (score 1):

Sher Khan above, and particularly schauveau @ https://github.com/OpenShot/openshot-qt/issues/2053 precipitated my suspicion that it may be a combination of issues; I DO NOT KNOW as I haven't tested all of them, but I suspect it may be the width of the video not being divisible by 8 (e.g. 1280 yes, 1366 not) 1366 x 768 screens may be the root cause of the issue as well as the screen recorder.
It worked fine for me when using Simple Screen Recorder, I simply (pun intended) selected "Record a fixed rectangle" and changed the width to 1360 (divisible by 8) as opposed to 1366.

As schauveau stated, it appears that the last six pixels are the issue.

That was it.  Never use a preposition to end a sentence with.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Windows user. The same thing happened with me, but I did a little experiment and found the solution. All instructions are as per Microsoft Windows interference

1. After saving the recorded video, by right-clicking it and select properties.
2. Under the *Details* tab -> scroll down to *Video properties*.
3. Note down the values of "frame width", "frame height" and "frame rate".
4. Start OpenShot and editing everything.
5. Click *Export*, a dialog box should open.
6. Under the *Advanced* tab -> select *Profile* -> Select any Profile (it doesn't matter) by default take "HDV 720 24p".
7. Now apply values from 'step 3' to corresponding properties and export it.

Now OpenShot will export the resolution the same as from screen recorder